# Dockerfile using RHEL8 UBI images to register subscription

Tags: dockerfile, rhel8

I need to access several packages in the CodeReady repo on ubi-8 (`ubi-8-codeready-builder`).  It appears that I cannot access these packages unless I use a RHEL subscription.

What is the standard practice for building RHEL8 UBI images that are registered with the RHEL subscription?  How do you build a Dockerfile for this?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to pass the USERNAME and PASSWORD into the Dockerfile.
Then use the args to register subscription and enable CodeReady as shown
in the Dockerfile below.

```
# Basing the build image on RHEL UBI image.
# See `docker search registry.access.redhat.com/ubi` 
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.1

ARG USERNAME
ARG PASSWORD

# CodeReady contains packages required for develpers (i.e. imake)
# Must register system using RHEL subscription in order to access these packages
RUN subscription-manager register --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD} \
  && yum repolist \
  && subscription-manager attach --auto \
  && subscription-manager repos --enable=codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms \
  && yum repolist
```

Then I can store USERNAME and PASSWORD as variables in a passwords file (passwords should be added to .gitignore so its not pushed to any central repos) and call docker build as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
source passwords

docker build \
  -t my-image:v1 \
  --build-arg USERNAME=${USERNAME} \
  --build-arg PASSWORD=${PASSWORD} \
  .
```

Note: one thing to be aware of is that each time you build the image you'll be registering the image with RedHat.  I'm not completely certain but I would assume at some point it might reach some limit of number of systems registered.